# Intellij Plugin Custom Compiler Not Invoked Despite entry in META-INF/services

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I am trying to create an intellij plugin to compile Latex. I am following [this documentation](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/frameworks_and_external_apis/external_builder_api.html) for implementing the External Build API. However, my `LatexBuilderService` class which extends `BuilderService` is not invoked when I press the "build project" button. How do I make sure my `LatexBuilderService` is properly invoked?

Under `src/main/resources/META-INF/services` I created a file called `org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.BuilderService` which contains the the fully qualified name for my `BuilderService.` In paticular, it has the text: `build.builders.LatexBuilderService`

The `extensions` part of my `plugin.xml` looks like this

```xml
<extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
    <compiler.buildTargetScopeProvider implementation="build.scope.LatexBuildScopeProvider"/>
    <compileServer.plugin classpath ="/home/philip/IdeaProjects/latex-compile-proof-of-concept/build/libs/latex-compile-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" />
</extensions>
```

and have confirmed with print statements that `getBuildTargetScopes` in my `LatexBuildScopeProvider` class which extends `BuildTargetScopeProvider` is being called whenever the "build project" button is pressed.

Classes I've extended

- `LatexBuilder` extends `TargetBuilder<LatexBuildRootDescriptor, LatexBuildTarget>`
- `LatexBuilderService` extends `BuilderService`
- `LatexBuildScopeProvider` extendeds `BuildTargetScopeProvider`
- `LatexBuildRootDescriptor` extends `BuildRootDescriptor`
- `LatexBuildTarget` extends `BuildTarget<LatexBuildRootDescriptor>`
- `LatexBuildTargetType` extends `BuildTargetType<LatexBuildTarget>`

Here is my code for `LatexBuildScopeProvider`

```
public class LatexBuildScopeProvider extends BuildTargetScopeProvider {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<TargetTypeBuildScope> getBuildTargetScopes(@NotNull CompileScope baseScope,
                                                           @NotNull Project project,
                                                           boolean forceBuild) {
        System.out.println("getBuildTargetScopes was called");

        Stream<Module> modules = Arrays.stream(baseScope.getAffectedModules());
        List<String> moduleIds = modules.map(Module::getName).collect(Collectors.toList());

        TargetTypeBuildScope scope = CmdlineProtoUtil.createTargetsScope(
                LatexBuildTargetType.instance.getTypeId(),
                moduleIds, // Sometimes referred to as module names in other plugins
                forceBuild);
        return Collections.singletonList(scope);
    }
}
```

and my code for `LatexBuilderService.` None of the print statements or exceptions are triggered when I press the "build project" button.

```
public class LatexBuilderService extends BuilderService {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<LatexBuildTargetType> getTargetTypes() {
        System.out.println("calling getTargetTypes");
        return Collections.singletonList(LatexBuildTargetType.instance);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<LatexBuilder> createBuilders() {
        System.out.println("calling createBuilders");
        return Collections.singletonList(new LatexBuilder());
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public List<? extends ModuleLevelBuilder> createModuleLevelBuilders() {
        throw new NotImplementedException("createModuleLevelBuilders");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best place for plug-in development and IntelliJ IDEA API questions is the [dev forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development).

Your question is [already answered](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360003335979-External-Builder-API-Specific-Implementation-Details?page=1#community_comment_360000430400) there and I'd continue the discussion in the forum as it's more convenient in this case.